# Object Args is not a member of package views.html.b3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework, datepicker, playframework-2.0

I'm learning about Play Framework from a course in Udemy. The following code doesn't work and I would like to know why.

I have created a tag folder and `datePicker.scala.html` as instructed:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: b3.B3FieldConstructor)

@*
* A datepicker component based on
* https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
*
*@

@b3.inputFormGroup(field, withFeedback = false, withLabelFor = true, b3.Args.withDefault(args, 'class -> "form-control")) { fieldInfo =>

  <div class='input-group date' id='@{fieldInfo.id}z' data-date="@fieldInfo.value" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">

    <input type='text' id="@{fieldInfo.id}" name="@{fieldInfo.name}" value="@fieldInfo.value" @toHtmlArgs(fieldInfo.innerArgsMap)/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" >

          $('#@{fieldInfo.id}z').keydown(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          });

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#@{fieldInfo.id}z').datepicker({
              format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
              orientation: "top left",
              calendarWeeks: true,
              autoclose: true,
              todayHighlight: true
            });
          });

  </script>
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
activator clean && activator compile
[info] Loading project definition from /home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/project
[info] Set current project to consulting-services-inc (in build file:/home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 17, 2016 7:18:40 PM
[info] Loading project definition from /home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/project
[info] Set current project to consulting-services-inc (in build file:/home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 16 Scala sources and 18 Java sources to /home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/valter/git/learning/consulting-services-inc/app/views/tags/datePicker.scala.html:9: object Args is not a member of package views.html.b3
[error] @b3.inputFormGroup(field, withFeedback = false, withLabelFor = true, b3.Args.withDefault(args, 'class -> "form-control")) { fieldInfo =>
[error]                                                                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 17, 2016 7:18:47 PM
```

I'm using the latest version of Play Framework `2.5.6`. I also have downloaded the instructor's entire project from Dec 2015, and is not working anymore, he was using version `2.4.2`. So I'm kind of stuck with this problem now.

If you're wondering about plugins versions, or other parts of my code, please [visit my repository](https://bitbucket.org/valterhenrique/consulting-services-inc).

Any tip, help, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Args` object belongs to `views.html.bs` package, not `views.html.b3` (https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap/blob/master/core-play25/app/views/bs/Args.scala). So what you need is something like:

```
@b3.inputFormGroup(
    // (...)
    bs.Args.withDefault(args, 'class -> "form-control")) {
        // (...)
}
```